# FontAwesome 5 react, icon visible upon hover

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I've been reading some of the answers here and I'm still not sure yet whether its a font awesome 5 svg issue or a react one. The icon is visible but when I hide it and hover over it the icon just doesn't pop up again.

```
import React from 'react';

import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";
import './Controls.css';

const controls=(props)=>(
  <div className="controls">
    <FontAwesomeIcon icon= "play" size="6x" className="iconn"/>
  </div>


);

export default controls;
```

here's my css...

```
.controls .iconn{
  position:relative;
  color: #fff;
  top:2.2rem;
  left:3.0rem;
  display: none;


}

.controls:hover .iconn{
  left: 3.6rem;
  display:block


}
```

if anyone has any solution please help me out

Comment: try give `controls ` div a width and height. I guess when the FA icon is hidden that div has no height at all so it has no size to allow any hover.

Comment: @Yongzhi thank you so much, that was the issue.